# ¿Cuál es el origen de la palabra "gurrumino"?

Tags: etimología, historia

En la respuesta de @Gustavson a [**What is the name of the tense formed with “llevo + gerundio”?**](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/22859/what-is-the-name-of-the-tense-formed-with-llevo-gerundio/22862#22862) cita (negritas mías):

> ... ni que me vean siempre sonriente y hecho un **gurrumino** inseparable de esa mujer que lleva aguantando palizas diez y siete años (*Gómez Serna, Automoribundia*)

Consultado el DLE por [**gurrumino, na**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Jtxio7m), indica que es **de origen incierto** y significa

> 1. adj. coloq. Ruin, desmedrado, mezquino.
>   2. adj. *Bol.* p. us. cobarde (‖ pusilánime).
>   3. adj. *Nic.* pequeño (‖ de poca estatura).
>   4. m. y f. *Sal.* Chiquillo, niño, muchacho.
>   5. m. coloq. p. us. Hombre condescendiente en exceso con su mujer.
>   6. f. *Ext. y Cuba.* Pequeñez, fruslería, cosa baladí.
>   7. f. coloq. p. us. Condescendencia excesiva de un hombre con su mujer.

La entrada más antigua que he encontrado en el CORDE es de 1737:

> Assí no culparía yo al que digesse aferes por negocios inútiles; amollecer por ablandar; bravería por bravura; comienzo por principio; **complacedor por gurrumino**; desalforjar por sacar de las alforjas ... (*Gregorio Mayans y Siscar, Orígenes de la lengua española, 1737*)

lo que concuerda con que, en las entradas del [**Diccionario de Autoridades**](http://web.frl.es/DA.html), se indica que es **voz moderna**:

`GURRUMINA`. s. f. Obediencia indebida, contemplación excessiva a la propria muger. **Es voz moderna.** Latín. Uxori indebita submissio.
`GURRUMINO`. s. m. El marido que obedece indebidamente, y contempla con excesso a su muger. **Es voz moderna.** Latín. Vir uxori indebitè submissus.

Pero no encuentro ninguna indicación etimológica, ni de cómo ha ido adquiriendo las restantes acepciones recogidas actualmente en el DLE [2](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Jtxio7m).

¿Cuál es el origen de gurrumino y cómo adquirió esas acepciones adicionales?

Comment: Es curiosa la acepción de "niño, muchacho". En el pueblo de Jaén de donde es mi familia materna a los niños pequeños se le llama "gurrupato" o "[gurripato](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JtqVztS)".

Comment: Me apunto *gurrupato*, mola mucho

Answer (score 2):

Cito el diccionario etimológico abreviado de Covarrubias:

> GURRUMINO, 1734 [...]. Palabra familiar de origen incierto; quizá es alteración de **gorobino*, deriv. de **goroba* por joroba; comp. el asturiano *gurrumba* 'joroba', *gurrumbiela* 'jorobado', bogotano *gorobeto* 'torcido, combado'; la *j-* de *joroba* viene de un *ḥ* arábigo, consonante que a menudo da *g* en romance. Pero también es posible que *gurrumina* significara básicamente 'arrullo amoroso' y que con este sentido derivara de la raíz onomatopéyica vasca *urru* y *urruma* 'arrullo del palomo', 'ronroneo del gato', 'ronquido'.

Al parecer el significado original de la palabra es el correspondiente a la acepción 5: "el que tiene contemplación excesiva por la mujer propia", tal y como recoge el *Diccionario de autoridades*.